# Laravel: How to use redirect inside a function

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, declaration, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I want to Redirect my views inside the function like when admin goes to admin page, teacher goes to teacher page and student goes to student page.

Im getting an unexpected error with the else :(

**Here's my function**

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $validator =  Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'username' => 'required',
        'pass1' => 'required'

    ));

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::route('getLogin')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    else
    {
        $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;

        $auth = Auth::attempt(array(
            'username' => Input::get('username'),
            'password' => Input::get('pass1')
        ), $remember);

        if($auth)
        {

            $admin = User::where('isTeacher', '0')->where('isAdmin', '1')->get();

            $teacher = User::where('isTeacher', '1')->where('isAdmin', '0')->get()

            if($admin)
            {
                return Redirect::route('admin.index');
            }
            else if($teacher)
            {
                return Redirect::route('teacher.index');

            }
            else
                return Redirect::route('student.index');
        }
        else
        {
            return Redirect::route('getLogin')->with('fail','You entered the wrong login credentials. Please try again.');
        }
    }
}
```

I want to redirect the route using the function instead inside of my blade. Is this possible?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: unexpected error at else :/

Comment: there are so many else in this code, which else ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if($auth)
    {

        $admin = User::where('isTeacher', '0')->where('isAdmin', '1')->get();

        $teacher = User::where('isTeacher', '1')->where('isAdmin', '0')->get(); <-----
```

you missed a `;` in that line.

**Additional info:**

```
User::where('isTeacher', '0')
```

you have to use an operand as 2nd argument. e.g.

```
User::where('isTeacher','=', '0')
```

Comment: oh oxo;; Thanks about that!! XD ahhahaha sorry sorry